# how to play mp3 file in .net compact framework

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [is there a clean way to play an mp3 sound in the compact framework 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204562/is-there-a-clean-way-to-play-an-mp3-sound-in-the-compact-framework-3-5)

how to play mp3 file in .net compact framework...
not playing mp3 file can anybody help me ....

thanks advance

```
using (var player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(FilePath))
{
    player.Play();
}
```

Comment: you got stange "using" usage there. C# using syntax is something alike using (....) { foo(); }

Comment: @Veronica it's not strange (`using` with an assignment), it's OK and quite common.

Comment: @Morawski It is OK but it isn't common and readable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a nice library for .Net

http://naudio.codeplex.com/

Documentation for mp3 playing at:
http://naudio.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MP3