# Getting stuck on mp3 player for windows ce 5.0 using c#

Tags: c#

What .net assembly can be used to play mp3 files on Windows Mobile 5.0?

I have not had success with the windows media player component.

Please provide an example in your answer.

Comment: what did you try? is there any reason why you cannot use the answer already given to you in your other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204562/is-there-a-clean-way-to-play-an-mp3-sound-in-the-compact-framework-3-5/1972056#1972056 ?